# Unzip: cannot find or open file

Tags: linux

My goal is to install The Oracle enterprise manager on my linux system. I successfully unzipped the first 2 zip files. For some reason I get the following error when trying to unzip the last file

```
unzip em12104_linux_disk3.zip
unzip:  cannot find or open em12104_linux_disk3.zip, em12104_linux_disk3.zip.zip or em12104_linux_disk3.zip.ZIP.
```

I'm using rhel 5.4 linux btw

Edit:

```
ls -l em12104_linux_disk3.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oracle 2727123784 May 26 23:33 em12104_linux_disk3.zip
[oracle@uch-km Downloads]$ unzip em12104_linux_disk3.zip
unzip:  cannot find or open em12104_linux_disk3.zip, em12104_linux_disk3.zip.zip or em12104_linux_disk3.zip.ZIP.
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is size of the file (~2.54GB). Try to use another program like p7zip.

btw. Which architecture You hae? IA32 or x86-64?